# What does this function do? A lot of lambdas

Tags: python

These lambda functions return the result 13. Why is that? Can someone please help me understand them? Thank you,

```
two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y, y))
one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x)+f(y))
h=one_to_two(two_to_one (lambda x, y: x*y))
print (h(3, 2))
```

**Output:**

```
13
```

Comment: Alright thanks for your help.

Comment: @DavidPitts Just remove the image and post it as text.

Comment: Play the role of the computer. Grab a pencil and write down each step as the computer would execute it and what the values aer.

Comment: ...or turn them into functions and then use python's `pdb` or `pdb3` debugger to do the stepping for you.

Comment: @tdelaney i tried it , and i got the wrong answer , im  not sure how to read what each line is doing , and how each lambda is interacting with the function.

Comment: Ok , i'll try thanks!

Comment: I broke it out into function but unfortunately pdb's output wasn't very good at showing what's going on. But the functions themselves were much easier to read.

Comment: @DavidPitts if you try something and it doesn't work, that's important information to add to your questions. Just sayin'.

Comment: Why the negative votes? I think this is a hard question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breakdown version:

```
def two_to_one(foog):
    def foo1(y):
        return foog(y,y)
    return foo1

def one_to_two(foof):
    def foo2(x,y):
        return foof(x)+foof(y)
    return foo2

def foo3(x,y):
    return x*y

h = one_to_two(two_to_one(foo3))

print h(3,2)
```

How the functions will be called:

```
Step1:
two_to_one(foo3) returns foo1. Now foog = foo3

Step2:
one_to_two(foo1) returns foo2. Now foof = foo1

Step3:
h = foo2

Step4:
h(3,2) will call foo2(3,2)

Step5:
foo2(3,2) calls:

#foof(x)    foog(x,x)
foo1(3) --> foo3(3,3) --> 3*3
                           +   --> 13 #return this from foo2
foo1(2) --> foo3(2,2) --> 2*2
#foof(y)    foog(y,y)

Step6:
print 13 #print return value of h(3,2)
```

Comment: I was about to post that! Explanatory text would be nice. The functions return closures.... inner functions that are bound to their parameters but haven't been executed yet. So, `h` is a function and `h(3,2)` calls it.

Comment: @tdelaney This is very confusing :D I was figuring out the flow. I'll improve

Comment: @tdelaney I give up now.

Comment: This is really helpful , thank u very much

Comment: @MYGz Hi , i had a test a few days ago and your answer is the reason i was able to answer a similar question , i divided it into diffrent functions and understood the logic  , thanks alot!

Comment: @DavidPitts Very nice to hear that. Worth the time.

Answer (score 3):

This script uses lambda to create anonymous closures - functions that are bound to variables that are used whenever the function is called. To figure out what it does, we can make everything explicit and litter the code with prints to see what is going on. Interestingly, all the calculations are done in `h(3, 2)`

```
# two_to_one = lambda g: (lambda y: g(y, y))
def two_to_one(g):
    """Return a function `func(y)` that applies input function `g`
    in the formula: g(y, y)
    """
    def _two_to_one_closure(y):
        print("_two_to_one_closure calls: {}({})".format(g.__name__, y))
        rc = g(y, y)
        print("_two_to_one_closure returns", rc)
        return rc
    return _two_to_one_closure

# one_to_two = lambda f: (lambda x, y: f(x)+f(y))
def one_to_two(f):
    """Return a function `func(y)` that applies input function `f`
    in the formula: f(x) + f(y)
    """
    def _one_to_two_closure(x, y):
        print("_one_to_two_closure calls: {}({}) + {}({})".format(
            f.__name__,x,f.__name__,y))
        rc = f(x) + f(y)
        print("_one_to_two_closure returns", rc)
        return rc
    return _one_to_two_closure

# h=one_to_two(two_to_one (lambda x, y: x*y))
def _anon(x, y):
    print("_anon", x ,y)
    rc = x*y
    print("_anon returns", rc)
    return rc

g = two_to_one(_anon)      # create a _two_to_one_closure that will
print("g", g)              # call _anon when called

h = one_to_two(g)          # create a _one_to_two_closure that will
print("h", h)              # call `g` when called

# print (h(3, 2))
print("do the calculations on 3, 2")
i = h(3, 2)                # call h, which is a _one_to_two_closure
print(i)
```

Running this, you get

```
g <function two_to_one.<locals>._two_to_one_closure at 0x7fca5165a1e0>
h <function one_to_two.<locals>._one_to_two_closure at 0x7fca5165a268>
do the calculations on 3, 2
_one_to_two_closure calls: _two_to_one_closure(3) + _two_to_one_closure(2)
_two_to_one_closure calls: _anon(3)
_anon 3 3
_anon returns 9
_two_to_one_closure returns 9
_two_to_one_closure calls: _anon(2)
_anon 2 2
_anon returns 4
_two_to_one_closure returns 4
_one_to_two_closure returns 13
13
_two_to_one_closure 2
_anon 2 2
13
```

Comment: Thank you , helped me alot to understand the order.